# Vim how to print the mode I am in

Tags: vimrc

Let's say I have a visual selection:

[image]

How would I print the mode from the commandline? I've tried doing:

```
:'<,'><C-U>echom mode()
```

And a few variations of that, but haven't been able to figure out how to see that I'm in visual (or visual-line) mode. How would I properly do that?

Comment: Are you trying to show your mode at the bottom of the screen with `showmode` or to print the current mode you're in with `mode()`?

Comment: @Biggybi print the mode -- for me to use in a command (this is to debug it)

Comment: Please, read `:h mode-switching` carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typically pretty hard to be able to tell the mode from a function or even a mapping, since usually the commands you'd have to execute to retrieve the current mode will switch you to another mode already.

For example, when you do `:echo mode()` you'll have switched to command-line mode with the `:`, so it will simply return `c` rather than the normal or visual mode you were in.

This is mentioned in [`:help mode()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#mode%28%29):

> This is useful in the `'statusline'` option or when used with `remote_expr()` In most other places it always returns `"c"` or `"n"`.

For specific situations, such as querying which Visual mode was used last, you can use [`visualmode()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#visualmode%28%29), but that tells you nothing about whether you're coming to the current mode from Visual mode, or how long ago Visual mode was last used...

---

You might have less interference by using an `<expr>` mapping, in which case `mode()` will be evaluated before most mode changes happen.

```
function! Debug(mode, saymode)
  let cmd = "echom 'Mode is [".strtrans(a:saymode)."]'\r"
  if a:mode ==# 'n'
    return ":".cmd
  elseif a:mode ==# 'i'
    return "\<C-o>:".cmd
  elseif a:mode ==# 'v'
    return ":\<C-u>".cmd."gv"
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <F2> Debug('n', mode())
inoremap <expr> <F2> Debug('i', mode())
vnoremap <expr> <F2> Debug('v', mode())
```

But even in that case, it's not really completely reliable. For example, if you're in "Select" mode, Vim will switch you to the corresponding Visual mode before executing a mapping, so this will show the Visual mode rather than Select mode...